# How can I link https links in a PDF document automatically

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF File, where some https://domain/file.html in it. When I open it in Acrobat or PDF Architect the https lines are automatically interpreted as LINKS an I can click on it to open them in Chrome. How can I prepare this PDF, so that in every PDF Reader can these https lines interpreted or substituted als https-links, so that I can click on them again?